# Existence proof for bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider two sets $A, B$ and two bijective maps $f_1, f_2$ defined between them, such that
$$
f_1: A \rightarrow B, \text{ s.t. } h(a)\leq h(f_1(a)) \text{ for all } a \in A \\ f_2: B \rightarrow A, \text{ s.t. } h(b)\leq h(f_2(b)) \text{ for all } b \in B
$$
for some function $h: A \cup B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. 
Now, assuming $f_1, f_2$ exist, **does the bijective map $g_1$**, such that 
$$g_1: A \rightarrow B, \text{ s.t. } h(a) = h(g_1(a)) \text{ for all } a \in A $$
**always exist?** 
Showing the reverse is of course trivial, but I am wondering if this direction also holds. Also, if it does, does it hold for finite, countably infinite and uncountable sets $A, B$ alike?

Please help to find a suitable title for this question or suggest tags.

Comment: oh yes, will fix. thanks!

Comment: It doesn't hold for countably infinite sets, for instance, take $A=\{\hbox{odd numbers}\}$,$B=\{\hbox{even numbers}\}$, $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=x+1$ and $h(x)=x$. Clearly there is no such $g_1$.

Comment: @JulianMejia "Smear" out each integer in that example to a small interval instead, and the exact same expressions give a counterexample for uncountable $A, B$.

Comment: @JulianMejia thanks mate!